# Get tweet-count via twitteR-package

Tags: r, twitter, package

I'm having some trouble with R and the [twitteR-package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR).
My aim is to get the total tweet from a given user. The *user-class* offers a *statusesCount*-field. I don't know how to get the value from this field.
The [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/vignettes/twitteR.pdf) only offers examples with tweets from public timelines and even there I can't get the total counts.

The example in the vignette looks like this (p. 5):
`sapply(publicTimeline(), function(x) x$getStatusSource())`

I can extract even the ScreenName or the user-ID:
`sapply(publicTimeline(), function(x) x$getScreenName())`
`sapply(publicTimeline(), function(x) x$getID())`

In fact, the *publicTimeline*-function catches random users and I'd like to have given users.

Anyone can help me?

Regards,
Arne

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to first `getUser` for a specific user. Then, you can use `str()` to understand the structure of that user. The `@` symbol is used to access fields in S4 objects.

Example:

```
> library(twitteR)
> user <- getUser("@twitter")
> user@statusesCount
[1] 1087
```

Comment: You can also use `statusesCount(user)`

Comment: `user@statusesCount` does not work. That seems a little strange to me.

Comment: @ahs85: the code provided above should work if you try it verbatim. All statusesCount(user) is doing is extracting the statusesCount slot from user.